# Scrapy only render the last url in a list of url

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, splash-screen, scrapy-splash

I'm working on a web crawler which crawls the https://e27.co/ website. I used **scrapy-splash** python library, and also **docker**.

The problem is that scrapy only renders the last url of the url list.

Moreover, when I open the `response.body`, the page automatically redirects me to an '**oops**' page.

I tried to stop/make splash not to follow the redirection but it fails.

Here is my **spider**:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
import csv



class e27_spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'e27'
    start_urls = ['http://www.e27.co/startup/uber', 'http://www.e27.co/startup/urban-ladder']
    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url = url, callback = self.parse, args={'http_method': 'POST','follow_redirects':False})
            # yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse, meta={'splash':{'args':{'html':1, 'png':1,'dont_process_response':True}},'handle_httpstatus_list':[302],'dont_redirect':True})

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = 'asd-%s.html' % response.xpath('//*[@id="page-container"]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/h1/text()').extract_first()
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)

        final_data = {}
        startup_name = response.xpath('//*[@id="page-container"]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/h1/text()').extract_first()
        startup_founding_date = response.xpath('//*[@id="page-container"]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/p[3]/span/text()').extract_first()
        startup_description = response.xpath('//*[@id="page-container"]/div[4]/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/p/text()').extract_first()
        final_data['Name'] = startup_name
        final_data['Founding Date'] = startup_founding_date
        final_data['Description'] = startup_description

        print (final_data)
```

**Settings.py**:

```
BOT_NAME = 'webcrawler'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['webcrawler.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'webcrawler.spiders'
SPLASH_URL = 'http://192.168.99.100:8050'
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
}
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
}
DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'
```

Here are the **logs**:

```
2017-06-27 01:04:53 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'webcrawler', 'DUPEFILTER_CLASS': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter', 'HTTPCACHE_STORAGE': 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'webcrawler.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['webcrawler.spiders']}
2017-06-27 01:04:53 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2017-06-27 01:04:53 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-06-27 01:04:53 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-06-27 01:04:53 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-06-27 01:04:53 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-06-27 01:04:53 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-06-27 01:04:53 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-06-27 01:04:54 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.e27.co/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2017-06-27 01:04:54 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://192.168.99.100:8050/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2017-06-27 01:04:54 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST http://www.e27.co/startup/urban-ladder via http://192.168.99.100:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
{'Name': None, 'Founding Date': None, 'Description': None}
2017-06-27 01:04:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST http://www.e27.co/startup/uber via http://192.168.99.100:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
{'Name': 'Uber', 'Founding Date': None, 'Description': '\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tUber is a technology company that is changing the way the world thinks about transportation. They are building technology people use every day. Whether it’s heading home from work, getting a meal delivered from a favorite restaurant, or a way to earn extra income, Uber is becoming part of the fabric of daily life.'}
2017-06-27 01:04:57 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-06-27 01:04:57 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 1876,
 'downloader/request_count': 4,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 192303,
 'downloader/response_count': 4,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 26, 17, 4, 57, 366774),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 5,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 4,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 4,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 4,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 4,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 4,
 'splash/render.html/request_count': 2,
 'splash/render.html/response_count/200': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 26, 17, 4, 53, 892873)}
2017-06-27 01:04:57 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Any idea why does my **splash** only render the last url of the list?

Comment: There are 2 `DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST http://www.e27.co/... via http://192.168.99.100:8050/render.html`, not 1.

Comment: yes, but the scrapy could not get the content of the other one. the same applies if i add more url in the list, it only get the content only for one url. any ideas why? @paultrmbrth

Comment: No, I don't. Do you need to do a POST request? Have you tried adding a wait time?

Comment: not as far as i'm concern. the website only require GET request, and one of it is OPTION. i'm quite new in debugging through the http method. In addition, the response.body also redirect me to a particular page. Could that be the reason?

Comment: So you can get rid of `'http_method': 'POST'`. I have not tried your spider (and will probably not do it), so my advice would be to check in the Web UI (go to http://192.168.99.100:8050 in your browser) and test your URLs.

Comment: okay i tried removing the http_method, which result as the same as before. also the i checked through the web UI, it worked just fine. The content is renderred without any problem. i guess something happening in the splash itself (if i change the url list, the last url is the only content that is loaded correctly). really need help here :(

Comment: You may want to open an issue on Splash on GitHub.